# How to reset the force shutdown by default setting of a Tomcat server configured in IntelliJ 2020.2?

Tags: intellij-idea

There was once a dialog that asked me to wait or to force shutdown of the Tomcat server in configured and ran in IntelliJ 2020.2. In the dialog there was an option to always kill the server immediately and I remember clicking it one day. I'd like to reset the default shutdown behavior to wait rather than kill immediately, ideally displaying the dialog on every shutdown offering me to kill the server as opposed to just doing it.

In an ideal world there was a configuration in form of a checkbox or dialog asking me whether I want  an option to disappear forever rather than punishing a missclick so severly.

Comment: Do you mean action on stop button?

Comment: The dialog was shown when pressing the stop button

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?